# how to redirect HTTPS url with server name to HTTPS url with SSL certificate name

Tags: asp.net, https, url-rewriting

My requirement is to redirect URL from **https**://abc/Testconnect to https://abc.xyz.com/Testconnect.

I am not able to redirect to **https**://abc.xyz.com/Testconnect and it is displaying as "The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address"

I am able to redirect from **http**://abc/Testconnect to https://abc.xyz.com/Testconnect.

Here xyz.com is the SSL certificate and abc is the Machine where application is deployed(application is deployed in IIS of the machine-abc)

I am trying to modify URL rewrite related code in web.config file of the application to redirect the URLs.

Kindly let me know how to achieve it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

When you hit any HTTPS site, the *first* thing that happens (after the connection is established) is an SSL handshake, where the browser says to the server "give me the certificate for abc". That has to succeed before *anything* else can happen. Your IIS rewrite rules won't even be looked at unless the SSL handshake succeeds.

So if you want to redirect from https://abc to https://abc.xyz.com, then you need a valid certificate for abc.

See [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/08/02/ssl-handshake-and-https-bindings-on-iis/) for a description of the SSL handshake. About halfway down there's a good diagram showing the back-and-forth communication. At the bottom of that diagram is "Exchange messages" where all the IIS/HTTP logic starts.